# Get JSESSIONID value and create Cookie in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies

I'm using a Web RestFUL API from my client in AngularJS.

```
app.controller('LoginController', [
    '$http',
    '$cookies', 

    function($http, $cookies) {
      this.credentials = {};

      this.http = $http;

      this.login = function() {
        console.log(this.credentials);

        var authdata = btoa(
            this.credentials.username +
            ':' +
            this.credentials.password
        );

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;

        console.log($http);

        var res = $http.post("http://API_NAME/library");

        res.success(function(data, status, header){
            alert('Successfull func');

            console.log($cookies.get('JSESSIONID'));
        });

        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Error Log');
        });
     };
   },
]);
```

Then, i have this Http headers Response

```
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=azekazEXAMPLErezrzez; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

I'm using ngCookies to get the JSESSIONID value and then create it manually in my browser, but i can't access it.

I already saw all the posts about this in StackOverflow, but they are deprecated or completely unclear.

Thanks for your interest and help.

Comment: Why do you need to access JSESSIONID in Angular? That cookie is marked as HttpOnly, i.e. it can not be accessed in JS.

Comment: I didn't get that the send of the cookie JSESSIONID was automatically handled.
I thought i had to do it manually.
Comments helped me to understand this. Problem Solve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get HttpOnly cookies with JavaScript. That is the whole purpose of the HttpOnly flag.

That said, you shouldn't need to. The cookie should be sent automatically with any request to the same server. If you are dealing with cross-origin XHR requests, set `your_XHR_instance.withCredentials` to `true` to include cookies.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`? Since it is a JavaScript object, it would be difficult to set it server side.

Comment: thanks ! I just had to set in app.config :
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

check on my RestFUL server that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" was properly setting and "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" set to true.

It works fine.
Thanks for your help :)