# Spring Boot Login API with Angular 6 Frontend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, angular6, session-management

I am using Spring Boot as backend and Angular 6 as frontend.
I have created a login API which takes username and password as parameters and checks in a DB if both are matched. It will return a successful response. Afterward, I set a cookie as below

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", URLEncoder.encode(employee.getEmpName(),"UTF-8" ));
cookie.setMaxAge(1800);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

I am getting a response with user details fine in frontend (in the login component). But when I call another API endpoint from a child or the other component, it receives a new cookie id (`JSESSIONID`) from the backend.

So my question is how to maintain the same session in all component and where I need to keep the login component and other components.

Comment: what do you mean by "where I need to keep the login component and other components"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JSESSIONID value and create Cookie in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990836/get-jsessionid-value-and-create-cookie-in-angularjs)